# Data pass as argument/parameter in Getx getting lost when i am refreshing flutter web page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am working on flutter web. I have used Getx for state management. When I trying to Pass data as argument or parameters in Getx web flutter, I am able to access data on another page. But my problem is if i refresh second page then i am not able to access data. after refresh getting null. How to fix this issue ?

Passing data from page one

```
Get.toNamed("/example_page", arguments: {'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2'};

 var  data = {
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "message" : "hi!"
   };
  Get.toNamed(YourRouteName.name, parameters: data);
```

On the next page:

```
final args = Get.arguments;
print(args); // output: {arg1:val1, arg2:val2}


 print(Get.parameters['email']);
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I resorted to saving the important params in preferences.
And this problem is present whether you use GetX or not on the web.